# Transform string into an arithmetic operation

Tags: python, string, integer

I have this string:

```
x = "2x4, 2x5"
```

I want to transform it into the following operation:

```
x = (2 * 4) + (2 * 5)
```

So the final result will be 18.

Do you have any idea ? If the solution can be flexible to strings with different number of items (ex: "2x4, 2x5, 2x7") it would be great !

Thanks !

Comment: You should write a parser. How to do that is beyond the scope of a single question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `operator.mul` to multiply those numbers,and use `sum` to add them,Try this below:

```
from operator import mul
x = "2x4, 2x5, 2x7"
print(sum(mul(*map(int, i.split('x'))) for i in x.split(', ')))
```

Result:

```
32
```

Answer (score 0):

[split](https://docs.python.org/fr/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) is your friend

```
def compute(equation):
    mults = equation.split(",")
    _sum = 0
    for mult in mults:
        terms = mult.split("x")
        products = 1
        for term in terms:
            products *= int(term)
        _sum += products
    return _sum
```

Answer (score -1):

Using Eval

**Code**

```
def eval_str(s):
  ss = s.replace(',', '+').replace('x', '*')  # , -> + and 'x' -> *

  # disallow import and lamda functions (to make eval safe)
  if '__' in ss or 'import' in ss or 'lambda' in ss:
      return None  # disallow items that could make eval unsafe
  return eval(ss, {}, {})   # make eval safer by setting globals and locals to empty dictionary
```

**Usage**

```
x = "2x4, 2x5"
print(eval_str(x))
# Output: 18

x = "2x4, 2x5, 2x7"
print(eval_str(x))
# Output: 32
```

Comment: Maybe they think `eval` is unsafe,it is not recommend to use.

Comment: @KevinMayo--it's unsafe if you don't restrict it's default arguments of globals and locals see [blog post](http://lybniz2.sourceforge.net/safeeval.html).

Comment: Using `eval` is a direct way,but the person who downvote don't like `eval`.I don't know,IMO I also don't like `eval()`,too.

Comment: @KevinMayo--actually I don't like eval either since simply assigning globals and locals to {} can be worked around see [this other blog](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).  But, there is an easy defense for the attacks mentioned (i.e. disallowing strings with import and lambdas) which would be suitable for the current problem.